# Customize title of a plotly graph in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Is it possible to apply a header to a plotly barplot like below in R?

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
p <- plot_ly(s.df, x = ~Farm, y = ~Acreage, color = ~Crop) %>%
         layout(barmode = "stack", xaxis = list(title = ''), margin = list(b = 140),
               title = "ACREAGE")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the total background color with e.g. `layout(plot_bgcolor='green', paper_bgcolor="green")`.

Examining Plotlys title style with the Developer tools ("Inspect Element") and copying their title properties, you can create your own title for the chart:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(  
        radioButtons("titleChoice", "Plot", choices=c("Nothing", "Acreage", "Percentage", "Costs")),
        conditionalPanel(condition="input.titleChoice != 'Nothing'",
                         uiOutput("plotTitle"),
                         plotlyOutput("plot"))
      )
server <- function(input, output){
   output$plotTitle <- renderUI({
       div(style='background-color:green; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:17px; font-family:"Open Sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif', 
           input$titleChoice)
   })
   output$plot <- renderPlotly({
     plot_ly(diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~clarity, color = ~price) %>%
       layout(barmode = "stack", xaxis = list(title = ''), margin = list(b = 140))
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note the important piece here is

```
div(style='background-color:green; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:17px; font-family:"Open Sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif', TITLE)`
```

This is what the result looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is helpful indeed however, I'm looking for something such that I can change the name dynamically. The title should be a part of the plot such that it disappears when there's nothing to plot. This is why I'm looking for something that can be done in the server. I have a RadioButton that changes between Acreage, Percentage and Costs.

Comment: Using a conditionalPanel, I edited my answer to make the title dynamic. Next time, it would be helpful to supply s.df in your original post.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I just have a final question if you don't mind answering. Is there a way to export this as a PNG with both the title and graph?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but you can change the whole "paper" color if that doesn't look to ugly, then the title is included in the downloaded Plotly PNG: `%>% layout(paper_bgcolor="green", title=input$titleChoice, titlefont=list(color="white"))`